# Android progress circle waves

Tags: android, graphics, draw, geometry, progress

I'm trying to make a progress circle for android. I found this in the Data Usage in Miui v5.
In the center, the line is not straight but it is like a wave.

[image]

Can someone help me to make it?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you might looking for. The bottom left progressbar. Take a look [here](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress)

Also you can take a look [here](https://github.com/john990/WaveView) for the wave view you are looking for.

The implementations are:

**CircularProgress:**

```
<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.CircleProgress
        android:id="@+id/circle_progress"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        custom:circle_progress="20"/>
```

**CircleProgress:**

```
<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.CircleProgress
        android:id="@+id/circle_progress"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        custom:circle_progress="20"/>
```

**ArcProgress:**

```
<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
        android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
        android:background="#214193"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        custom:arc_progress="55"
        custom:arc_bottom_text="MEMORY"/>
```

Hope that helps!!!